# accessing dom part that were load with ajax works in a weird way

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i will try to explain as clearly as i can.
What i did was loading a part of the page using ajax and after using simple jquery to access that part of the dom that was loaded with ajax.
in the main.html i loaded dom part, the dom part comes from a php file that just echoes the html i need, lets say that the php file it is called call_me.php
in the main.html the js was already loaded, so basically the ajax loaded dom could not be accesed by it for some reason. what i did it to work was to put the js that i needed to work on that dom part in the call_me.php that part of js was not echoed by the call_me.php and for some reason it worked, i searched the js code in inspect element and could not find it at all, can someone please tell me what is going on? or explain me how this works?
the ajax code that i used is:

```
$('.general').click(function(){
    $('.contents').html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'src/user_setting.php',
        data: 'target='+$('.user_target_id').val(),
        success: function(msg){
            $('.contents').html(msg);

        }
    });
});
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php 

    require '../config/global.php';
    if (isset($_GET['target']) && isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        $target = security($_GET['target']);
        $from = security($_SESSION['userId']);
    echo<<< html
    <input name = "target" type = "hidden" class = "target" value = "$target">
    <input name = "from" type = "hidden" class = "from" value = "$from">
    <div class ="container form-container2">
    <div class="alert alert-success confirm">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        Mesajul a fost trimis cu success !
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-error confirm-error">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        Mesajul nu poate fi trimis !
    </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>Subiect</span></td> 
                <td><input name = "title" class = "span3 title" type = "text"  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><textarea name = "body" class = "span5 msg" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><button class = "btn btn-inverse send">Trimite mesaj</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
html;
    }
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".confirm").hide();
    $(".confirm-error").hide();
    $('.send').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "src/send_message.php",
               data: $(".target").serialize()+"&"+$(".from").serialize()+"&"+$(".title").serialize()+"&"+$(".msg").serialize(), 
               success: function(data)
               {
                 if (data == "ok") {
                    $(".confirm").slideDown();
                    $(".confirm-error").hide();
                    $(".title").val("");
                    $(".msg").val("");                  
                }else{
                    $(".confirm-error").slideDown();
                }
               }
         });
    });
 </script>
```

if there are better methods using javascript on the dom that was loaded with ajax please tell me, i am kainda new in the web development

Comment: Most likely jQuery is stripping out the scripts and executing them before appending the html. One of the reasons returning scripts with html via ajax is a bad idea, unless you separate out the scritps before sending it to `.html()` so that you can execute them after.

Comment: to be honest i don`t really get it :(